# What does ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException mean and how do I get rid of it? Here is a code sample that triggers the exception:

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been working on some code in java and I just ran into an error and i'm not sure why because I just ran some code that was just like this and it worked just fine.

```
    String [] month = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

    double [] temperature ={54.3, 57.0, 62.5, 67.6, 74.3, 79.2, 80.9, 80.4, 77.8, 70.1, 62.8, 56.3};    
    double [] precipitation ={3.5, 3.4, 4.3, 2.9, 3.2, 6.8, 6.1, 6.6, 4.4, 2.5, 2.2, 2.6};  
 for( int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.print(""+month [index] +".        "+temperature [index]+"         "+precipitation [index]);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: `May` i remind you somthing?

Comment: What is it?...............

Comment: Never mind I just got it lmao

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: It is not, that post inspired me to ask this question because I had the same problem, just for different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inspection, I can see that your `month` array is missing the month of `May`, and therefore only has 11 elements in it.  As a result, when you iterate over the 12 elements in the `temperature` array, you will get an array out of bounds exception during the final temperature, because there is no corresponding enter in `month` at that position.

To fix this, just make sure that `month` and `temperature` are the same size:

```
String [] month = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
```

Comment: Ah thanks didn't catch that.